# Symfony3 Form-Error Parameters not working

Tags: php, forms, translation, symfony

i have problem with using **Symfony 3** Form Error component. I need to add my own error to form, but parameters are not replaced with values.

```
$form->get('price')->addError(
    new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError("Maximal value is %price% %currency%.", 
    null, 
    array('%price%' => 100, '%currency%' => 'YPI')));
```

I tried use parameters with `{{ currency }}` and `{{ price }}` as in other validators but still not works.

There is this way: http://quedig.com/questions/35271649/symfony-form-error-message-parameters-usage/ but it's not the best way - I  still believe in better soloutions where i can use classic translations without placing result from translating service here.

What is best usage for FormError? Symfony3 manual is silent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages passed to the constructor of `FormError` have to be already translated. Otherwise, they will be shown as is. So your code could look something like this:

```
// $translator should be the "translator" service
$message = $translator->trans('Maximal value is %price% %currency%.', [
    '%price%' => 100,
    '%currency%' => 'YPI',
]);
$form->get('price')->addError(new FormError($message));
```

By the way, I suggest to use message placeholders instead of real messages as the string to be translated (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html#translation-keys)

Comment: It's the same solution as i posted in my original query. But it seems no other solutions there. Now I have no idea, why FormError has arguments like parameters :-D..